# What's is the difference between two ways to use function pointer?

Tags: c

I have countered a problem about use function pointer

```
typedef int (*zly)(int,int);

struct fuc{
   zly name;
};

int zzc(int a,int b){ 
    return b - a;
}

int mfc(zly z,int a,int b){ 
    return z(a,b);
    //return (*z)(a,b);
}

int main(){
   struct fuc *s = malloc(sizeof(struct fuc));        
   //s->name = &zzc;
   s->name = zzc;
   int res = mfc(s->name, 5,10); 
   printf("%d\n",res);

   // two has same address. 
   printf("%x -- %x \n",&zzc,zzc);

}
```

I want to know the difference between s->name = &zzc and s->name = zzc ?

Thank you .

Comment: Both are the same as `s->name = ***zzc`, but you need to get a paid certificate before you're a three-star programmer.

Comment: Come on, 1.5 million questions on stackoverflow, and you don't think this might be one of them already?

Comment: @Kaz you are right, I will search it before I ask it,thank you.